# Are all the apps in Windows Store now UWP apps?

Tags: uwp

Are all the apps in Windows Store now built on the Universal Windows Platform?  I see they all have links which indicate you must install Windows 10 in order to use them on a pc.  However, I don't see anything indicating they are UWP apps which may be because that's the default?

Answer (score 1):

All apps ARE NOT necessarily UWP apps.  Windows 8.1 apps do run on Windows 10, just not the other way around.  Not every company or indie developer has updated their apps to support UWP.  All apps that were previously in the store for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 will still run and be available respectively.

Answer (score 0):

UWP apps run on all windows 10 devices like PC, tablet, mobile, hololens, IoT devices, Xbox.
I think we can differentiate UWP apps from other apps if the apps description says that it will run on Xbox, Hololens, PC, tablet etc.

example UWP apps whose description says they are available on PC, Xbox etc are:
[Baconit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/baconit/9wzdncrfj0bc?&activetab=pivot:overviewtab), [Dolby Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/dolby-access/9n0866fs04w8?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), [AwesomeTube](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/awesome-tube-app-for-youtube/9nblggh69mg4#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

note: see the 'Available On' section.

Reference: [Other famous UWP apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928294/what-are-the-famous-apps-that-are-built-using-uwp)