# What are the famous apps that are built using UWP?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

1. I am building a UWP(universal windows platform) app, I am looking for famous apps that are built using UWP. I want to look at their UI etc for reference.
2. I came to know that calculator app we are using in our PCs is a UWP app. I want to know some more famous UWP apps in market that are available in store or elsewhere to check them.
3. twitter, flipkart used to be UWP apps previously. But they changed to (Progressive Web Apps)PWA.
   reference: https://www.windowscentral.com/twitter-updates-its-windows-10-uwp-app-pwa-support-push-notifications

Comment: Most UWP apps are Microsoft (build with Windows). UWP has not attracted that much attention. These times are times of changes... I would seriously consider other options: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/05/19/introducing-winui-3-preview-1/ also https://www.telerik.com/blogs/building-modern-performant-desktop-apps-winui-30-the-way-to-go a well wri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Microsoft apps are built with uwp.

Some third party apps I'm using are also beautiful like, Aurora Music, Dolby Access, Intel Graphics Command Center, 网易云音乐, Files Uwp, Unigram, Newsflow， Microsoft To-Do，2Day，Bing dictonary, MyerSplash, etc.

Comment: what are the famous market apps that are consuming WinUi 2.x in UWP? We can see how rich, interactive they are making their UI by consuming the add-ons of WinUI. Currently WinUi 2.x series is stable in market from last 1.5 years, WinUi 3 is about to release by the end of this year or next year.

Comment: Currently I can't see any apps on store using WinUI. Maybe I'm short-sight.

Answer (score 0):

These are also the other [Uwp apps](https://medium.com/@Arlodottxt/uwp-community-launch-2020-1772efb1e382). And also:
1. onenote(there will two oneNotes: 'onenote 2016'(not this) and 'onenote'(this is uwp)).

2. mail, calendar, people, photos